# Is there a way to map column names to properties from my entity using Dapper?

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm considering in using dapper for my project, but first, I need to know if it:

1-) Can it map column name to my class properties? In my project, i have legacy tables that has no cool names.

2-) It works well with stored procedures? All my queryes relies on stored procedures. Its a company determination.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518119/mapping-entity-in-dapper.

Answer (score 0):

To map column names to class properties you can do something like this -

```
class YourClass {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then -

```
var yourclasscollection = connection.Query<YourClass>(@"select notcoolid as id, notcoolname as name from legacytable");
```

Comment: But I have many procedures, I dont want rewrite each procedure.
The procedure is like: select * from table , so I need to do some mapping from the entity