# Are there any disadvantage to use stored procedures with Dapper?

Tags: stored-procedures, dapper

I'm have recently started to learn about the micro ORM named [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). We usually are relying heavily on stored procedures in MSSQL databases in order to avoid T-SQL together with mixed up with our C# code.

What are your experience with Dapper and stored procedures? Does Dapper require inline T-SQL to fully utilize Dappers all benefits\features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are your experience with Dapper and stored procedures?

Dapper is ultimately an object mapper, which works using `ADO.Net` APIs internally, though it does Cache certain data structures to make queries faster, but it works quite efficiently with the Stored procedures.

> Does Dapper require inline T-SQL to fully utilize Dappers all benefits\features?

No, in-fact as Stored procedures are pre-compiled, so unlike Sql text queriues there's no scope of hard parse on every request, since optimum execution plan is already cached in the Sql Server.

In nutshell, stored procedures is indeed an ideal mechanism to use for dapper and SQl server combination for :

- Performance
- Clean and consistent code
- Doing complex database operations, like working with TVP, it can take lot of data in single call and work with it instead of multiple Network request uisng Text queries

Comment: Marc Gravell says that Dapper doesn't have any mapping layer in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9518214/294242 But I guess the mapping functionality have been implemented since 2012 which is the date he posted that answer... 

What is TVP?

Comment: @JonasAxelsson you have misunderstood that answer by Marc, Question says if you specify an entity and database result has different set of column names, how will it map? Marc says, there's no option, in fact even now there isn't an option by default, need to use one of the extensions to do the mapping, which overrides default Sql mapper, whose only purpose is to map columns with same name from Sql result. This does not takes away from the fact that Dapper is an object mapper, since it results in `IEnumerable<T>` and nothing to do with your question :)

Comment: Using Stored procedures with Dapper is indeed a standard mechanism used by number of enterprise systems